# F# Async Dispose

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I wrote this little web listener simulation:

```
Agent.Start(fun (_ : MailboxProcessor<unit>) ->
        let listener = new HttpListener()
        listener.Prefixes.Add(addr)
        listener.Start()

        let rec respondOut() = async {
                let! context = Async.FromBeginEnd(listener.BeginGetContext, listener.EndGetContext)
                use s = context.Response.OutputStream
                let wr = new StreamWriter(s)
                use disp = { new IDisposable with
                                member x.Dispose() =
                                    printfn "Disposing..."
                                    wr.Dispose() }
                wr.Write("Test")
                return! respondOut()
            }

        respondOut()
    )
```

I don't understand why Dispose is not called on disp on every loop?

As a side question, I'm doing all this because I want to test what is the proper behavior to respond text in a web service. I'm not sure if I should be doing:

```
use s = Context.Response.OutputStream
use sw = new StreamWriter(s)
    sw.Write("test")
```

or

```
Context.Response.Write("Test")
Context.Response.End()
```

or whatnot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, use reflector :). The use keyword create the scope of "using" till then end of the block. When used inside the async workflow if you de-sugar the async keyword  you will get something like:

```
Async.Bind(Async.FromBeginEnd(listener.BeginGetContext, listener.EndGetContext)
           (fun context ->
                use s = context.Response.OutputStream
                let wr = new StreamWriter(s)
                use disp = { new IDisposable with
                                member x.Dispose() =
                                    printfn "Disposing..."
                                    wr.Dispose() }
                wr.Write("Test")
                Async.ReturnFrom ( respondOut() )
                )
```

Now the call Async.ReturnFrom at last will continue calling the function recursively and if you replace the use with " C# using() { } " where the } bracket is after the Async.ReturnFrom then the dispose will never get called

Wrapping the use part in a do block should solve the problem:

```
let rec respondOut() = async {
                let! context = Async.FromBeginEnd(listener.BeginGetContext, listener.EndGetContext)
                do 
                    use s = context.Response.OutputStream
                    let wr = new StreamWriter(s)
                    use disp = { new IDisposable with
                                    member x.Dispose() =
                                        printfn "Disposing..."
                                        wr.Dispose() }
                    wr.Write("Test")
                return! respondOut()
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

`use` extends to the end of the block, so I would expect `Dispose` to be called *after* the recursive computation returns (which is never, in this case, since it loops unconditionally).  If you want to dispose of the resource earlier, you'll need to delimit the scope of the `use` binding somehow.  Perhaps something like this would work (I haven't tried it):

```
let rec respondOut() = async {
    let! context = Async.FromBeginEnd(listener.BeginGetContext, listener.EndGetContext)
    do! async {
        use s = context.Response.OutputStream
        let wr = new StreamWriter(s)
        use disp = { new IDisposable with
                     member x.Dispose() =
                         printfn "Disposing..."
                         wr.Dispose() }
        wr.Write("Test")
    }
    return! respondOut()
}
```

Comment: I don't think the inner `async` is needed. You can just wrap the `use` block in parens to make the disposal point explicit: `(use disp (* do something with disp *) )`.

Comment: @Daniel - you can't just use arbitrary expressions within a computation expression, but you could use `do (use ...)` instead of `do! async { use ... }`.

Comment: All good answers, marking Ankur's as answer as it provides more information and I found the do notation a little cleaner something I hadn't thought of doing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `disp` is optimized away in your compiled code since it isn't used. Try adding `printfn "%A" disp` on the next line.

Comment: Removing it and putting use on wr doesn't dispose that either and that is why I'm having trouble with the listener.

Comment: Yes works fine, but that is because it's disposed at the end of the anonymous function. Solves my current problem but leaves me definitely worried use bindings would not be disposed in async workflows. I'm thinking perhaps it's because the recursive call is not tail optimized away leading to what Tomas had mentioned being a kind of memory leak.

Comment: I think the leak occurs when using `do!` instead of `return!`, but maybe there are other cases as well.

Comment: I still prefer `using` to `use` because the point of disposal is more apparent.